# creating filters from selections (isotope)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I have four levels of filter, basically: format, region, demographics and interests.

```
<div class="form-div">
  <input type="checkbox" data-filter="i-newspaper">
  <input type="checkbox" data-filter="i-magazine">
</div>

<div class="form-div">
  <input type="checkbox" data-filter="i-northland">
  <input type="checkbox" data-filter="i-southland">
</div>

<div class="form-div">
  <select>
    <option value="4" data-filter="i-digital">Digital</option>
    <option value="1" data-filter="i-manufacturing">Manufacturing</option>
    <option value="2" data-filter="i-retail">Retail</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-div">
  <input data-filter="i-business-and-finance" type="checkbox">
  <input data-filter="i-careers-and-education" type="checkbox">
  <input data-filter="i-design-and-photography" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

The filters from isotope are based on what's checked/selected above.

I was using something like this:

```
var selectors = [];
$(".form-div").find("input:checked, option:selected").each(function(){
  selectors.push('.'+$(this).data('filter'));
});
selectors = selectors.join('');
```

Which was providing a selector like `.i-newspaper.i-magazine.i-northland.i-southland.i-digital.i-design-and-photography` (assuming these were the checked/selected form elements)

However, each `.form-div` is a separate set, so with the above selection I'd hope to get:

```
.i-newspaper.i-southland.i-digital.i-design-and-photography,
.i-newspaper.i-northland.i-digital.i-design-and-photography,
.i-magazine.i-southland.i-digital.i-design-and-photography,
.i-magazine.i-northland.i-digital.i-design-and-photography
```

How would something like this be achieved?

Let me know if my question needs more clarification...

Thanks

**EDIT**

Another alternative solution for this problem, is 'multi-level' filtering.

So filter by this set: `.i-newspaper, .i-magazine`

Then filter the subset by this set: `i-southland, .i-northland`

And so on and so forth...

**EDIT2**
JsFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/MkME9/

Comment: Your solution might be here http://jsfiddle.net/RRgjD/ or https://github.com/desandro/isotope/issues/143 or here http://fiddle.jshell.net/desandro/fgLUa/4/show/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look on my edit:
http://jsfiddle.net/MkME9/

This is what You need?

**EDIT**
This is correct?

http://jsfiddle.net/MkME9/6/

**EDIT LAST (I hope )**

http://jsfiddle.net/MkME9/9/

Comment: You might need to save a new version I think?

Comment: Well, all you're providing me in that fiddle is my code... I think you may have misunderstood the question.

Comment: so You get this: __.i-newspaper.i-magazine.i-northland.i-southland.i-digital.i-design-and-photography__  yes? And want have string __.i-newspaper.i-southland.i-digital.i-design-and-photography,
.i-newspaper.i-northland.i-digital.i-design-and-photography,
.i-magazine.i-southland.i-digital.i-design-and-photography,
.i-magazine.i-northland.i-digital.i-design-and-photography__ ??

Comment: Yes, basically each 'set' needs to get marked down *once* in every other 'set'.

Comment: You mean combination each with each yes?

Comment: yeah, so no two items from the same set are in the same selector string.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17044/discussion-between-woocash-and-ahren)

Comment: New version in edited post. Please check and tell if all work as intended now.

Comment: perfect! thanks! PS: I edited it again to make it a few less lines: http://jsfiddle.net/MkME9/10/ (if you're interested)